# Не могу запустить простое SpringMVC приложение

Tags: java-ee, spring-mvc, servlet, tomcat

Я создал контроллер:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json;charset=UTF-8" })
    @ResponseBody
    public List<User> getUser() {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("SpringModule.xml");
        UserDAO userDAO = (UserDAO) context.getBean("userDAO");
        return userDAO.findAllUsers();
    }
}
```

Также создал `ApplicationInitilizer`:

```
public class ApplicationInitilizer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    private static final String DISPATCHER = "dispatcher";
    public void onStartup(javax.servlet.ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebConfig.class);
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet(DISPATCHER, new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

И контекст `SpringModule.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <import resource="database/SpringDatasource.xml"/>
    <import resource="dataBeans/SpringUser.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Запускаю в Tomcat, перехожу по http://localhost:8080/users, в логе вижу:

```
28-Aug-2016 22:51:49.106 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory D:\Programs\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager has finished in 69 ms
28-Aug-2016 22:51:51.921 WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-10] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/users] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Если запустить как простое приложение из main класса, все работает корректно. Уверен, что проблема с тем, что я неправильно подсовываю ему контекст `SpringModule.xml`. Подскажите, что не так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring поддерживает несколько вариантов инициализации приложения - это XML, Java и Groovy. Вы используете вариант конфигурации приложения через Java аннотации. Об этом говорит эта строчка:

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
```

Если бы требовалось инициализировать контекст из XML через `WebApplicationInitializer`, то нужно так:

```
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebwApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        XmlWebApplicationContext appContext = new XmlWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.setConfigLocation("/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-config.xml");
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
            container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

[Посмотрите все варианты](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) в документации.

XML конфиг можно [импортировать](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-combining-java-centric), используя аннотацию `@ImportResource`.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"/path/to/database/SpringDatasource.xml", "/path/to/dataBeans/SpringUser.xml"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    // ...
}
```

В целом, XML конфигурация удобна в случаях, когда необходимо менять поведение приложения в runtime. Если у вас нет на то необходимости, используйте java конфигурацию и аннотации - тогда XML конфигурация вам вообще не требуется.

`ApplicationContext` в JEE приложении создавать вручную не нужно. Этот код в контроллере лишний.